# AngularJS + D3: First transition gets ignored

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am working on a donut-chart visualization by use of D3.js. I have created a directive `myWheel` and in the link function I `$watch` changes of the attribute `val` on the `<my-wheel>`-element.

Every time the data updates the visualization should update with a transition, which works fine, but the first time the transition is ignored. See ***[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cDz6DLdVbX1QChb5r5kM?p=preview)***.

If I delay (by `$timeout`) the first update of the data the transition is triggered.

Any ideas of where the problem is?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the `arcDataTween` function. When trying to interpolate between `this._current` and `a` in `d3.interpolate(this._current, a);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `selection.each` call on the enter selection of `donutDataSlice` that sets `this._current` to the datum as the paths are created.  This means that by the time you get into `arcDataTween` the first time, `this._current` and `a` are the same value.  So the interpolator doesn't do anything the first time through.

There are a couple of other issues as well.  In `arcDataTween` you have this:

```
function arcDataTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function(t) {
        return arcData(i(t));
    };
}
```

You are using `this._current` as the starting value of the interpolator but then you are setting `this._current = i(0)`.  Invoking an interpolator with 0 will return the starting value, so you are essentially setting `this._current` to the same value every time arcDataTween runs.  What you probably want is to set `this_current = a` (or, equivalently, `this._current = i(1)`).

As a small note about naming convention, the first argument in a custom tween is actually the datum so usually that is denoted with `d`.  Using `a` for this can be confusing because the third argument is the current attribute or style value of the element and that is usually denoted as `a` (e.g. `function arcDataTween(d, i, a) {}`).

Finally, your initial data has a `score` of zero and since you're using `score` as the value for the pie layout, this returns NaN for startAngle and endAngle in some cases.  I'm not sure what effect this has visually but it's probably not what you want.  The value accessor for the pie layout should always return a number that represents the proportion of the pie represented by that segment.  It might be better to filter out the data with score 0 before you calculated the segment values in order to avoid the NaN angles.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I have updated the [http://plnkr.co/edit/cDz6DLdVbX1QChb5r5kM?p=preview](plunker). The visuals looks ok even if i have `NaN` angles in the first iteration, but I wanted to avoid that, so now I filter out the data with score 0. However, I can't get the chart to animate on `.enter()`, even though I tweak the `this._current` values to allow `arcDataTween` to interpolate between two different values. Any ideas to solve that?

Comment: You need to be careful about caching the return value of interpolateObject because it actually uses the same underlying object for every call.  Here's a bug report with more details: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1030.  Does that help?